# how to use yolov3 with opencv.js in browser

Tags: opencv, dotnetnuke, yolo

I'm new to opencv.js and have a trouble with is as below:

```
let utils = new Utils('errorMessage');
    let cfg = 'yolo_file/test.cfg';
    let weights = 'yolo_file/test.weights';
    utils.createFileFromUrl('cfg', cfg, () => {
      utils.createFileFromUrl('weights', weights, () => {
        let img=cv.imread('imageSrc');
        let blob = cv.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, new cv.Size(800, 800), new cv.Scalar(0, 0, 0),true,false);
        let net = cv.readNet('cfg','weights');
        net.setInput(blob);
        let prob = net.forward();
        console.log(prob);
        //console.log(blob);
        //net.setInput(blob);
        //outs = net.forward(['yolo_82', 'yolo_94', 'yolo_106']);

      });
});
```

This code will get an error on this line `let prob = net.forward();`.
The error detail is "Uncaught 6575912".

Can you suggest me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yolo, each layer has an output so you need to specify the layers you want to forward. In your case it'd be something like this:

```
let outs = new cv.MatVector()
net.forward2(outs, ['yolo_82', 'yolo_94', 'yolo_106'])
```

Unfortunately, though, you cannot get the layer names from JavaScript as getUnconnectedOutLayersNames is not exported, so you either have to hard code it or change the source code and compile from source.

Comment: I tried this with YOLOv4 (though with the `layer_names = ["yolo_139", "yolo_150", "yolo_161"]`), and I'm still getting the Uncaught error. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I posted a question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72749914/yolov4-detection-in-opencv-js-causing-uncaught-exception

Comment: I know this answer was a while ago, so this is a long shot, but do you know how to leverage the outs MatVector? I extracted a few Mats from them, but not sure how to get information about the dnn results from the Mat.